# Android Java: Pulling content from URL

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm attempting to pull content from a website I made using an Android App. It is a translator app the returns a string based on the URL variables put in.

However, whenever I get the url back I get a variation of com.example.reviantranslator.RetrieveFeedTask@b1eed738 instead of the translated string I expect.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String english = et.getText().toString();
                String revian = et2.getText().toString();
                if (!english.isEmpty() && revian.isEmpty()) {
                    String[] words = english.split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            revian = revian + queryDB(words[i], false);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    et2.setText(revian);
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public String queryDB(String word, boolean revian) throws IOException {
        String variab = "le";
        if (revian) {
            variab = "lr";
        }
        String fullurl = "http://maereti.com/p/Revian/revian.php?"+variab+"="+word;

        RetrieveFeedTask RTF = new RetrieveFeedTask();

        AsyncTask<String, String, String> out = RTF.execute(fullurl);

        String output = out.toString();

        return output;

    }

    public void ToastThis(String words) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "toast function "+words, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




}
```

And the RetrieveFeedTask class:

```
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    URL url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String outputLine = "";
        Looper.prepare();
        MainActivity MA = new MainActivity();

        try {
             URL url = new URL(urls[0]);      
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = outputLine + inputLine;
            }


            MA.ToastThis(outputLine);

            in.close();

            return outputLine;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "!! I am error !!";
        }




    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not retrieving the result from your `AsyncTask` but just converting the task itself to a string. Try changing

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> out = RTF.execute(fullurl);

String output = out.toString();
```

to

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> out = RTF.execute(fullurl);

String output = out.get();
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you so much!